# GIT in VS2017r - How do I recover from a Team Explorer git Repo Sync that failed because tip is behind remote tip

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, git-pull, team-explorer

How do I get the Master branches of my remote repo and my local repo back into sync in Team Explorer?

**Situation:**
I have my app code in VSTS in a remote git repo.  I do all my work in Master, normally on my local (Dallas) machine, and use VS 2017 Team Explorer "SYNC" to periodically sync it up to the remote repo on VSTS.

On 25 Aug I made some changes to the code but had not yet committed them.  On 26 Aug I had to go for a three day visit to Austin.  While in Austin, I had to make some changes to the code so I cloned the repo from VSTS to my laptop, made the changes, committed them (see commit 8af in log below), and synched back to VSTS.

Upon my return to Dallas on 29 Aug, I went into the local machine, realized I had some uncommitted work, and committed it (see commit 310 in log below).  I then tried to sync with the master on VSTS and got the "*tip is behind*" error (see log below).

Tried a pull and got another error:

Pull operation failed.
The pull would overwrite your local changes to the following 3 files:

```
.vs/slnx.sqlite
/Account/Logout.cshtml
/App_Data/RESTORE BackupFile to SQL 2016 localdb.sql
```

From that point, trying to follow the (helpful?) hints and error messages, I got into even deeper trouble, added some more local commits, and am now quite confused.  The beauty of the Git integration in VS 2017 is it keeps you from having to know a lot about git.  That is also the evil in that setup!  I am pretty clueless when I have to work beneath the abstractions of VS 2017

I want to end up with history in origin and in the local Dallas repo to look like this

```
 Commit     ORIGIN  Local      Notes
 3d6                X(HEAD)    X(HEAD)  
 db9                X          X
 5e6                X          X
 310                X          X
 8af                X          X
 aa8                X          X
```

As opposed to the current state:

```
 Commit           ORIGIN     Local
 3d6                           X(HEAD)  
 db9                           X
 5e6                           X
 310                           X
 8af                X(HEAD)
 aa8                X          X    (common parent of 8af and 3d6)
```

Hopefully this description and the (edited) log info below will help someone help me out of this mess.  The original git documentation is turgid and incomprehensible. I tried Revert and reset (not fully understanding them) and got nowhere but in trouble.

My situation doesn't seem to fit any of the solutions I have been able to find via Googling and stack overflow.

My best guess is `git push -f` .  I am the only one working on this app.  However, I am worried given all the warnings on the dangers of git push -f.  If I did `git push -f` in the above scenario, what gets overwritten?  I am guessing it would be commit 8af (which is only on the origin master and has the common parent with the recent commits that would be pushed.  Is that a correct guess?

I would appreciate someone telling me what I need to do here.

**edited ("merged")log** 
(All commits, changes made, etc. were in Master branch)
C:\Users\rrrob\Source\VS2017Rafino>git log

commit 3d6 (HEAD -> master) *NOT IN ORIGIN* Thu Aug 30 08:38:18 2018 -0500

commit db9 Wed Aug 29 16:01:53 2018 -0500 *NOT IN ORIGIN*

commit 5e6 Wed Aug 29 15:08:24 2018 -0500 *NOT IN ORIGIN*

**29 Aug** returned to Dallas, committed previously uncommitted changes in Master and tried to sync.
received "Error encountered while pushing to the remote repository: rejected Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes  before pushing again." 
tried to Pull )(possibly Fetch?) from origin and received further error: "Pull operation failed."
commit 310 Wed Aug 29 15:05:47 2018 -0500 *NOT IN ORIGIN*  (parent is aa8)

**26** AUG went to Austin, cloned repo, made changes in master, committed, and sync'd with master in origin
commit 8af Tues Aug 28 12:56 5:56PM (UTC) *NOT IN Dallas Local Repo* (parent is aa8)

**LAST Successful SYNC in Team Explorer**
commit aa8 Thu Aug 16 15:10:06 2018 -0500  *in Dallas and in origin*

commit a8b Tue Aug 14 10:32:43 2018 -0500

Answer (score 0):

After lots of googling and with great trepidation (since I could not find anything that exactly fit my circumstances), I did the following:

(1)I did a git stash to park the changes into the stash

(2) Did a pull - yielding 2 conflicts (both on the sql lite files that suddenly appeared in my solution after going to VS 2017 from VS 2013)

(3)Resolved the 2 "both modified" conflicts by doing a git add on them

(4) Committed the results of all this

(5) Back to VS Team Explorer to Sync - success!

There was no skill involved, just sheer, dumb luck.  Any foray into git proper is, at least for me, a white-knuckle journey.

I suspect that the cause of this was my making changes in the cloned repo (while I was on the road) in the *Master branch*.  I probably should have done so in a *new branch*, push the new branch up to the remote, then issued a pull request to remind me to merge the new branch once I got back to my home location.

On another note, I do believe that when MS introduced the SQLlite DB to track IDE state, that they failed to consider its effect on Team Explorer.  Even though I have the .VS directory in the ignore file, the changes to the db always show up in the changes window in Team Explorer.  Confusing!